# Replace a single string in file at specific position with multiple new strings

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, scripting

I want to replace a single string in a file at a specific position with some new strings. Lets say I want to search for "BAD" in a file which looks like this:

```
MAD
DAD
BAD
DAB
BED
```

So now I want to replace BAD at position 3 with the following:

```
BAD-1
BAD-2
BAD-3
```

The resulting file should look like that:

```
MAD
DAD
BAD-1
BAD-2
BAD-3
DAB
BED
```

I tried something with sed:

```
sed "s/old/new/g"
```

But this will only changes a single line.
Any ideas?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
sed 's/^BAD$/BAD-1\nBAD-2\nBAD-3/' file

MAD
DAD
BAD-1
BAD-2
BAD-3
DAB
BED
```

---

Use awk for range control:

```
awk -v n=3 '/^BAD$/{for(i=1; i<=n; i++) print "BAD-" i; next} 1' file
```

Comment: Thank you! But is there a way to simplify this step? Maybe with range oder seq?

Comment: Perhaps OPS needs the -i flag.